# Does Leyline of Singularity works on tokens?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If [Leyline of Singularity](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=107697) is in play, will  my opponent be able to have multiple "2/2 zombie tokens" in play?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does count for tokens; you will not be able to have multiple tokens with the same name. The name of a token is defined by the spell that created it:

> 110.5c A spell or ability that creates a creature token sets both its name and its creature type. If the spell or ability doesn’t specify the name of the creature token, its name is the same as its creature type(s). A “Goblin Scout creature token,” for example, is named “Goblin Scout” and has the creature subtypes Goblin and Scout. Once a token is on the battlefield, changing its name doesn’t change its creature type, and vice versa.

So in your example, if an effect creates a 2/2 Zombie token, then the name of that token will be "Zombie."

Furthermore, the legendary rule does apply to tokens:

> 205.4d Any permanent with the supertype “legendary” is subject to the state-based action for legendary permanents, also called the “legend rule” (see rule 704.5k).

and

> 110.5e A token is subject to anything that affects permanents in general or that affects the token’s card type or subtype. A token isn’t a card (even if represented by a card that has a Magic back or that came from a Magic booster pack).

Comment: @ikegami, I copied from http://wiki.mtgsalvation.com/article/Token. I see now that it mentions "2008" next to the rules quote... is mtgsalvation not reliable? I've used that for a lot of rule lookups! Anyway, thanks for updating with the latest rules quotes!

Comment: for more, see [Dark Depths](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=121155). It creates a legendary token.

Comment: @GendoIkari Most of the comprehensive rules don't change that often, so most of what you find on MTGSalvation should be accurate, but you never know where something might have changed. It's probably better to refer to the actual CR from Wizards' site. There's also [this](http://www.yawgatog.com/resources/magic-rules/), which is kept up to date, but is technically still not canonical.

Answer (score 1):

A permanent is a card or token on the battlefield.<sup>[CR 110.1]</sup> If you have tokens on the battlefield, Leyline of Singularity will make them Legendary.

The legendary rule affects permanents, so it does affect tokens.<sup>[CR 704.5k]</sup>

The token's type is irrelevant. The legendary rule compares names.<sup>[CR 704.5k]</sup> However, a token's name is usually the same as the type as which it was created. Some effects that create tokens give them a name (e.g. [Cloudseeder](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cloudseeder)).<sup>[CR 110.5c]</sup> For the rest, the token's name is the same as its creature type. For example, the token created by [Vile Rebirth](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Vile%20Rebirth) is named "zombie".

If your opponent's 2/2 zombie tokens are named "zombie", they will have to put all but one in their graveyard.

---

> 110.1. A permanent is a card or token on the battlefield. [...]

> 110.5c A spell or ability that creates a creature token sets both its name and its creature type. If the spell or ability doesn’t specify the name of the creature token, its name is the same as its creature type(s). A “Goblin Scout creature token,” for example, is named “Goblin Scout” and has the creature subtypes Goblin and Scout. Once a token is on the battlefield, changing its name doesn’t change its creature type, and vice versa.

> 704.5k If a player controls two or more legendary permanents with the same name, that player chooses one of them, and the rest are put into their owners’ graveyards. This is called the “legend rule.”